# npm (react navigation)module is not updated

Tags: reactjs, npm, module, navigation

when i install react navigation module like this

these module requires somethig like react-native
but i installed and package.josn have that module
how can i do?

---

[image]
+ react-navigation@4.2.2
+ uuid@7.0.2
+ react-navigation-tabs@2.8.2
+ react-navigation-stack@2.2.3
removed 2 packages, updated 4 packages and audited 72980 packages in 8.487s

10 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 4 low severity vulnerabilities
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

### PS C:\Users\dys07\react-native-in-action\CitiesApp>

### and packge.json is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When this thing happened to me, I use to upgrade the warning modules.
Like,

```
npm install uuid@latest 
npm install request@latest
```

etc.
On command prompt and then all vulnerabilities fixed.